# Watir: Why does 'visible?' and 'exist?' fail on Window Method?

Tags: ruby, watir

Issue:  I am attempting to check if another/different browser with a different title is now opened.  If so, I want to work within that browser.  For some reason, "visible?" or "exists?" do not seem to be acceptable.  I am new to this but trying my best to review all online documentation and examples, but I can't seem to figure out why this simple method fails.  I went onto Watir API site, but the examples are sparse.

**Error:**
test2.rb:68:in `<main>': undefined method`visible?' for # (NoMethodError)

**Ruby Code:**

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"
require "rspec"
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "rspec/expectations"
require "test/unit"

if @browser.window(:title => "Web site Login").visible?
  @browser.window(:title => "Web site Login").use do
  begin
    @browser.driver.find_element(id: "ctl0UserName").send_keys ""
    @browser.driver.find_element(name: "ctl00ContainerID$btnNext").click
    @browser.driver.find_element(id: "ctl00_C").send_keys ""
    @browser.driver.find_element(name: "ctl00$ContentPllateContainerID$btnNext").click
    #Click on the drop down option for Pathway
  end
else 
  put "no login screen"
end
```

Comment: Based on the documentation, the [`Watir::Window` class](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Window) doesn't have `visible?` method.  It does have `exists?` and `present?` methods though.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, this worked when I changed it to the following.  Not sure why.

```
        if @browser.window(:title => "Web site Login").exists?
        @browser.window(:title => "Web site Login").use do
```

Answer (score 0):

I just re-wrote the Window class for Watir (there were some issues with referencing windows that had recently closed). present, exists and visible do not have any meaningful distinction. Either the window is there and usable or it is not. visible is not an allowed (useful?) call, and exists and present are aliased.

Comment: Thank you Titus.  Do you know which document has these methods?  I went on the Watir site, but do you think there should be more examples provided?  Also when I search on keywords like visible?, I get empty results.  In some cases, I have to put a '#' sign in front of my keyword search in order to get a result back.  Thank you for your help.  Mark

Comment: This document from rubygems, http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Window, or the source code on github - https://github.com/convio/watir-webdriver/blob/master/lib/watir-webdriver/window.rb
I've heard a couple people comment that the website is confusing, and I think there are some outdated references on there... I'm meeting with a couple of the team members at a conference soon, and I'll bring up these concerns.